# Is possible to make list for input in Ionic 2?

Tags: html, list, input, ionic2

I need to make an input that show list of options while I'm typing some things such as this image (if possible)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think a ion-searchbar will do what you are looking for. After adding the searchbar, you will need to bind it to the array you would like the user to be able to filter through.

Take a look at [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/searchbar/Searchbar/) link from the ionicframework.